# How do you convert specific array values in a JSON response to be just the first value in the array?

Tags: go, graphql, dgraph

(Note, Dgraph isn't required for this problem; it's just the tool I am using where I am encountering the problem)

Let's say you have some structs

```
type AccountSettings struct {
    Uid      string `json:"uid"`
    DType    string `json:"dgraph.type"`
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Username string `json:"username"`
}

type Settings struct {
    Uid     string          `json:"uid"`
    DType   string          `json:"dgraph.type"`
    Account AccountSettings `json:"account"`
}

type Tag struct {
    Uid   string `json:"uid"`
    DType string `json:"dgraph.type"`
    Label Label  `json:"label"`
}

type User struct {
    Uid      string   `json:"uid"`
    DType    string   `json:"dgraph.type"`
    Settings Settings `json:"settings"`
    Tags     []Tag    `json:"tags"`
}
```

and you create a user and add it to your Dgraph database

```
user = User{
    DType: "User",
    Settings: Settings{
        DType: "Settings",
        Account: SettingsAccount{
            DType: "SettingsAccount",
            Name: "Billy Bob"
            Username: "billyboy123"
        },
        Tags: []Tag{{
            DType: "Tag",
            Label: "admin"
        }, {
            DType: "Tag",
            Label: "user"
        }}
    },
}
```

And then you query your Dgraph database like (assuming you have the uid of the user node)

```
{
  user(func: uid("0x1234")) {
    uid
    settings {
      account {
        name
        username
      }
    }
    tags {
      label
    }
  }
}
```

the response will come back as

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": [
      {
        "uid": "0x1234"
        "settings": [
          {
            "account": [
              {
                "name": "Billy Bob",
                "username": "billyboy123"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
        "tags": [
          {
            label: "admin"
          },
          {
            label: "user"
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So the problem is that the JSON response of Dgraph will return fields of struct types as arrays (presumably because there could potentially be multiple nodes pointing to a single other node), but since it's an array, you can't immediately marshal it with the `User` struct (because `User.Settings` is of type `Settings`, not `[]Settings`).

What would you do in order to marshal the Dgraph JSON response with the `User` struct (or any other kind of struct)?

It's important to note that the `settings` array in the JSON response should just be the first element in that array, but the `tags` array should still remain an array because that's what's specified in the `User` struct.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a custom Unmarshal as described here:

http://choly.ca/post/go-json-marshalling/

You use an alias by embedding the original `User` in an anonymous type that has a slice of `Settings` inside it that you Umarshal into like so:

```
func (u *User) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    type Alias User
    aux := &struct {
        Settings []*Settings `json:"settings"`
        *Alias
    }{
        Alias: (*Alias)(u),
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &aux); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    u.Settings = aux.Settings[0]
    return nil
}
```

A full working example is here (you need the same trick for the `AccountSettings`):

https://play.golang.org/p/FQWakX8B7OF